# PayPal "Confirm your email address" spam emails? I got 3 different mails within 10 hours

Tags: email

I got 2 emails within 12 hours containing the following:

> **Confirm your email address** Hello [Name] [Name],
>
> Confirm your email address now to let us know it really belongs to
>   you.
>
> Once that's done, you're ready to receive money.
>
> If you are unable to click the button below to confirm your email,
>   please follow this link https://www.paypal.com/us/ece/?cn=17526xx55
>   [button]Confirm your email[/button]
>
> Thanks,
>
> PayPal

I added the pseudo-markup for the button and the placeholders for the names. Both mails are addressed to different names and both names are very american-sounding.

I use an email address which is publicly available. As I maintain contact with a very low-skilled user base I cannot "encrypt" my address with "[at]" instead of @ or "dot" instead of ".". I receive a lot of spam on a daily basis but the very most of that gets filtered by gmail's spam filter. However, the mails I received from PayPal look very legit so I suppose someone wants to make money by linking his account to a wrong person. Does it work like that?

I wouldn't mind if it was a single mail because it might be someone who still had my email in his clipboard, but experiencing this 2 times within a day seems very strange to me.

I would be glad if anyone knew more about this.

PS: sorry if that's the wrong board for that but I wasn't sure where else to ask.

UPDATE: I now got the **third** mail, 14 minutes after I asked the question. Again, an exceptionally stereotypical name. As I am pretty sure I don't harm any real person here, here the names:

- Kelsey Boldin
- Byron Maddux
- Priscilla Wakeford

Should I post any RAW data of the mails? The links are actually pointing to https://paypal.com/... I think I am either getting trolled or scammed here

Comment: Did you contact Paypal support? I would imagine they'd know what the story is.

Answer (score 6):

These are likely to be authentic emails, what's most probable is that someone is trying to open a paypal account using your details. While it's hard to say for sure what's most likely is that the same person or people tried to use your email twice. It didn't work the first time, so they tried again. It's impossible to say for sure without more data.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a legitimate Email from Paypal but still its difficult to tell without looking at the email headers.
It is possible that someone tried to re-use your email address for creating another account but as per Paypal, only verified Emails are allowed to do transactions using Paypal.
I would recommend that you get in touch with PAypal support. They are very prompt.
https://www.paypal.com/selfhelp/home